# date normalization using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

I am doing a date normalization thing where a date not put in a valid format is changed to a valid format. For example

```
1|1/2002
```

becomes

```
01-01-2002
```

and

```
5|9-20
```

becomes

```
05-09-0020
```

delimiter is only limited to [- / | ] and any input which doesn't follow has already been thrown out the list.

re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)

I looked at the library example but really could not find anything that helps parsing the data.

```
>>> def dashrepl(matchobj):
...     if matchobj.group(0) == '-': return ' '
...     else: return '-'
>>> re.sub('-{1,2}', dashrepl, 'pro----gram-files')
'pro--gram files'
>>> re.sub(r'\sAND\s', ' & ', 'Baked Beans And Spam', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
'Baked Beans & Spam'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using capturing group:

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'\b(\d{1,2})\D(\d{1,2})\D(\d{1,4})\b')
>>> def repl(match):
...     return '{:0>2}-{:0>2}-{:0>4}'.format(*match.groups())
...
>>> pattern.sub(repl, '1|1/2002')
01-01-2002
>>> pattern.sub(repl, '5|9-20')
05-09-0020
```

Comment: that was really helpful! thank you! what is it called the thing :0>2  you did. I want to find out more. Thank you!

Comment: @LeonardLie, `0` is padding character. `>` is to right align. `2` is width.

Comment: @LeonardLie, See [Format string syntax](http://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings).

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll accept the answer after the timer.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
def format_date_string(data):
    zmap = {0:2, 1:2, 2:4}
    return "-".join(p.zfill(zmap[i]) for i,p in enumerate(re.split("[|/-]",data)))

print(format_date_string("1|1/2002"))    # 01-01-2002
print(format_date_string("5|9-20"))      # 05-09-0020
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

def convert_format(d):
    m = re.match('(\d+).(\d+).(\d+)', d)
    if m:
        m = [int(x) for x in m.groups()]
        return '%0.2d-%0.2d-%0.4d' % (m[0], m[1], m[2])
    else:
        return False

for d in ('1|1/2002', '5|9-20'):
    print convert_format(d)
```

output:

```
01-01-2002
05-09-0020
```

OR:

```
import re

def convert_format(d):
    m = re.findall('\d+', d)
    if m:
        m = [int(x) for x in m]
        return '%0.2d-%0.2d-%0.4d' % (m[0], m[1], m[2])
    else:
        return False

for d in ('1|1/2002', '5|9-20'):
    print convert_format(d)
```

Comment: is that a part of question ?